# Why is OnActivityResult() never called?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, onresume

This is how I start the Tab Activity

```
  Intent i = new Intent("walk.me.TAB");
        startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_RESULT);
```

Note: `STATIC_RESULT=-1` or `RESULT_OK;`.

This is how I finish the Tab activity

```
((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.gotherefav)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(ime!=null)
        {

        b.putString("ime",ime.toString());
        b.putIntArray("koordinati&kategorija", coordAndCat );

        b.putBoolean("klik", true);

        FinishWithResult(b);
        }
        return false;
    }});



public void FinishWithResult(Bundle b)
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.putExtras(b);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
     Log.i("in FINISH", "settig Activity Result");  
    finish();   
}
```

And here is my `OnActivityResult` implementation:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result");  
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DOJDE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result");
          if (requestCode == STATIC_RESULT) {
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DOJDE BUNDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Bundle preferenciOdTab = data.getExtras();
           if(preferenciOdTab !=null && preferenciOdTab.getBoolean("klik", true))
                  {
                    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
                     isFavorite=preferenciOdTab.getBoolean("klik");
                  drawFavorite(preferenciOdTab.getString("ime"),preferenciOdTab.getIntArray("koordinati&kategorija"));
                  }
                 }}
```

Why is `onActivityResult` never called and directly goes to `OnResume()` regardless of the documentation garantees that OAR will be called before OR? What I'm doing wrong? I dont have stated in manifest xml

> singleInstance

or

> singleTask

for the Main activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say STATIC_RESULT is -1?

The requestCode has to be a positive integer.

[startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Parameters

> intent The intent to start.
>
> requestCode    If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.